# TypecastingTechniques and Uncertainity

Tags: php

I am trying to filter the user's input using Typecasting techniques. But I dont know all of them, upon searching for more techniques used for Typecasting, I found a lot of issues discussed related to typecasting being uncertain and unsafe.

Please tell me How to typecast values in several formats like int and others? I only know how to typecast int by using `(int)$variable`. And Are they safe to rely on?

Comment: you don't downcast. **you "typecast"**

Comment: You can only downcast if you have a type hierarchy and the new type is “below” the former type. If both types just have a common super type, then you can’t call it downcasting but rather converting.

Comment: @stillstanding... Oops.. I only knew type upcasting and downcasting...

Comment: upcasting/downcasting is associated with OOP objects/classes, which apparently has nothing to do with your question

Comment: You are referring to "type casting", please edit your title and question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [filter_var](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) techniques, so far are the best filtering there is. Or if you have time you can implement a more serious [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much anything:

```
$var = (float)$var;
$var = (bool)$var;
$var = (string)$var;
// ...
```

The available types are here : [PHP Type Casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting). For an insight into how these work, read rest of the page (and chapter) and "Converting to ..." pages in that page.